# webpack require local javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, webpack-encore

After some nice years using Assetic for loading my assets in a Symphony project I am looking forward to move to webpack for creating my fronded. So far I figured out to load modules via npm and require them into my main.js file.

Currently I am struggling with finding out how to embed some old JS assets that exist in my project structure (somewhere in src/MyBundle/Resources/public/...). The Plugin I want to embed has a dependency on another file, also in my local workspace.

Using something like:

`import dependency from 'src/MyBundle/Resources/public/asset_dependency.js';
import plugin from 'src/MyBundle/Resources/public/myplugin.js';`

did not work so far. What point am I missing? Do I need to add it into my webpack.config.js, do I have to create module-file that embeds both assets?

Comment: You need a relative path.

Comment: I would start with either converting those old assets into es6 modules or write es6 wrappers around them. The dependencies need to be defined in the asset, it should be not the users responsibility to track all the dependencies recursively.

Comment: `did not work so far` -- recommend including the error you're getting. But I agree with @SLaks, most likely mistake is path is not relative.

Comment: Webpack is giving me warnings about missing dependencies for the plugin. But the Plugin works with the given dependency, so there is definitely no need to install more. As it is a third party plugin, I cannot convert the code. What does "need to be defined in the asset" mean? Should it work to require it in the right way in my main.js, or do I need to add some additional webpack config?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
var yourJSassets = require('../path/from/this/file/yourJS');
```

Obviously you need to make sure this line is somewhere webpack will find it from your entry point(s)